How to infer literal types for dynamic keys in context-based React components?
I'm working on a set of TypeScript and React components to create a navbar with scroll navigation. I'm using React context to manage the state and configuration for the navbar, including a list of navigationKeys that define valid targets in the navbar.
<NavbarProvider
  navigationKeys={['abstract', 'funding', 'attachments'] as const}
>
  <NavbarList>
    <NavbarItem to="abstract">Abstract</NavbarItem>
    <NavbarItem to="invalid-key">Invalid Key</NavbarItem> {/* Expected Type Error */}
  </NavbarList>

  <NavigationTarget name="abstract">Hello, World!</NavigationTarget>
</NavbarProvider>

The goal is to have TypeScript infer the type for to props on NavbarItem and name props on NavigationTarget based on the literal types provided in the navigationKeys array to NavbarProvider. Ideally, I want to and name to be restricted to only the values in this array, so TypeScript allows to select from union of allowed keys or throw an error if an invalid key is used.
Here's a simplified version of the current setup:

NavbarProvider accepts an array of navigationKeys that I pass in as a constant tuple, like ['abstract', 'funding', 'attachments'] as const.
NavbarItem and NavigationTarget components receive to and name props, respectively, that should match one of the keys from navigationKeys.
I'm using createContext and useContext in a NavbarContext to provide the navigationKeys throughout the component tree.

TypeScript should restrict to and name to only accept values from the navigationKeys array provided to NavbarProvider. For example, if navigationKeys is ['abstract', 'funding', 'attachments'], then to and name should be a union of those literals ("abstract" | "funding" | "attachments"). When I attempt to pass a string like "invalid-key" that isn't in navigationKeys, TypeScript should throw an error.
Instead, to and name are still typed as generic string, so there's no type-checking against the specific navigationKeys provided. I've tried using generics in NavbarProvider and in NavbarContext, but the specific union type of navigationKeys doesn't propagate correctly down to NavbarItem and NavigationTarget.
Here's a simplified example of my component setup and current implementation:

NavbarContext:
type NavigationKey = string;

interface NavbarContextState<
  TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[] = NavigationKey[],
> {
  navbarKeys: TNavbarKeys;
}

const NavbarContext = createContext<NavbarContextState | null>(null);

const useNavbarContext = <TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[]>() => {
  const context = useContext(NavbarContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      `\`useNavbarContext\` must be used within \`NavbarContextProvider\``
    );
  }

  return context as NavbarContextState<TNavbarKeys>;
};



NavbarProvider:
interface NavbarProviderProps<TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[]> {
  navbarKeys: TNavbarKeys;
}

const NavbarProvider = <TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[]>({
  navbarKeys,
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<NavbarProviderProps<TNavbarKeys>>) => {
  const contextValue = useMemo<NavbarContextState<TNavbarKeys>>(
    () => ({
      navbarKeys,
    }),
    [navbarKeys]
  );

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
NavbarProvider.displayName = 'NavbarProvider';


NavbarItem (NavbarTarget is implemented similarly):
interface NavbarItemProps<
  TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[],
  TNavigationKey extends TNavbarKeys[number],
> extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Link> {
  to: TNavigationKey;
}

const NavbarItem = <
  TNavbarKeys extends NavigationKey[],
  TNavigationKey extends TNavbarKeys[number],
>({
  to,
  children,
  ...props
}: NavbarItemProps<TNavbarKeys, TNavigationKey>) => {
  const context = useNavbarContext<TNavbarKeys>();

  if (!context.navbarKeys.find((key) => key === to)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Invalid state. Key of to \`${to}\` is missing in Navbar navigation keys definition.`
    );
  }

  return (
    <Link
      to={to}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </Link>
  );
};
NavbarItem.displayName = 'NavbarItem';



Playground
How can I get TypeScript to enforce that to and name in NavbarItem and NavigationTarget only accept values from the navigationKeys array passed to NavbarProvider? Is there a pattern or technique to propagate literal types through React context in a way that TypeScript can infer?

Not possible using JSX syntax since all JSX have type "ReactNode".

I guess I could implement the navbar in a form of a hook, and return typed components this way. But it's as elegant anymore...

This is just simply not possible for the same reason that in foo('a', bar('b')) you can't make it illegal to call bar with 'b'. All that matters is the return type of bar('b'), but how you call it is completely unconstrained. And if the return type match up, then TS says everything is fine. And react components always return JSX.Element which has no additional typing about what it is. Does that answer your question? Would you like me to elaborate on that in an answer?

Thanks, Alex. I fully understand the core issue. My intuition led me to think, incorrectly, that the Context API example differs from your foo & bar example - if we add a constraint requiring B (consumer) to be callable only within the context of A (provider), we’ll be able to deduce types by inference.
